# Killing vectors of Schwarzschild: Solution

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, symmetry, vector-fields

In the solution of the Killing equations for Schwarzschild metric, $\nabla_\mu\xi_\nu+\nabla_\nu\xi_\mu=0$ for rotational part of symmetry participate Christoffel symbols with purely angular coordinates.

$$
0=\nabla_{(\theta}\xi_{\theta)}=\partial_\theta\xi_\theta-\Gamma^\mu_{\theta\theta}\xi_\mu=\partial_\theta\xi_\theta
$$

There is only one nonzero Christoffel symbol with $\theta\theta$ subscript, $\Gamma^r_{\theta\theta}$. But, it is not taken into account in summation. Why is  $\Gamma^r_{\theta\theta}$ not participating in summation over dummy indices?

Comment: To be clear, you are trying to find a Killing vector field $\boldsymbol \xi$ which has no radial component, right?

Comment: I am trying to find Killing vectors arising from rotational symmetry